# Appium - Native Android Application - Scrolling (Java)

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm trying to make automated tests on Android using Appium. 
Here is my code.

```
public class TestAndroidRealDevice {

private static AndroidDriver wd;
Dimension size;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.6.4-beta.2");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Samsung Galaxy S6");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/app-t3st-release.apk");

    wd = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(3000);

}

@Test
public void loginTest() throws Exception {

    WebElement login = wd.findElement(By.id("proceedBtn"));
    login.click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("customerBigBtn")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("haveAPassAlreadyBtn")).click();
    wd.findElement(By.id("countrySpinnerContainer")).click();

    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        if (wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[contains(text(), 'Poland (+48)')]")).isDisplayed()) {
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[contains(text(), 'Poland (+48)')]")).click();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            do {
                horizontalScroll();

            } while (wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView[contains(text(), 'Poland (+48)')]")).isDisplayed());
        }
    }

}

public void horizontalScroll()
{
    WebElement el = wd.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ListView");
    el.getSize();
    int x_start=(int)(size.width*0.60);
    int x_end=(int)(size.width*0.30);
    int y=130;
    wd.swipe(x_start,y,x_end,y,4000);
}

@After
public void tearDown () throws Exception {
    wd.quit();
}
```

After this commands my test fails.:

```
    wd.findElement(By.id("customerBigBtn")).click();
wd.findElement(By.id("haveAPassAlreadyBtn")).click();
wd.findElement(By.id("countrySpinnerContainer")).click();enter code here
```

In that screen I have drop-down menu where I want to find and select the specific Country. For this I should make scrolling (swipes) of drop-down-menu -  until my country (which I want to select from list) becomes visible on the screen.

But, unfortunately something were wrong here ;(

But I get an error that I could not find an element using supplied strategy and my test fails without any scrolling actions to find this element.

Any ideas? What I should to change?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling into desired element:

```
    MobileElement listItem = list
            .findElement(MobileBy
                    .AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                    + "new UiSelector().text(\"listItem text\"));"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is displayed will throw exception, if element is not visible.

If we want to check whether element is available on page we have to use findElements and then size of it. as shown below

```
driver.findElements(byVal).size() != 0
```

> If size is not equal to zero means it is available on page and we can
>   check isDisplayed for it to know the visibility of that element.

So try to write code as below in the place of `for (int i=0; i<4; i++)`

```
do {
    List<WebElement> allOptions = wd.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView"));

    for (WebElement webElement : allOptions) {
        if (webElement.getText().contains("Poland")) {
            webElement.click();
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        horizontalScroll();
    }
} while (!flag);
```

> This works for positive case and if you want to handle negative case
>   as well(give option which is not available in the drop down) then
>   update the code as per your requirement

Let me know if it works or you face any issue